# Texmaker. Keep configuration after closing

Tags: latex

When I close texmaker all the configurations I made reset and go back. Also the files I worked on don't show up in "open recent".

Has anyone had similar experience or a idea of how to solve this issue?

I am using Texmaker 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing a new LTS version 18.04 on my laptop. For some reason I don't know, the read and write permission was only given to root by default. I solved the problem in changing the write permissions of the configuration file.  This is done with the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod ugo+rw .config/xm1/texmaker.ini
```

Comment: I think you need to take ownership on this folder with something like `sudo chown $USER:$USER -R ~/.config` .